# Which thread are signal handlers (e.g. signal(SIGINT, crtl_c);) called on?

Tags: signals

Do signals interrupt the main thread or are they called from some OS thread? In other words, do I have to worry about thread safety when implementing signal handlers? For example, the following code will randomly fail if `on_sigint` is called on a separate thread. Are they? Will it?

```
#include <csignal>
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE hSigint;

void on_sigint(int sig)
{
    if (hSigint != NULL) SetEvent(hSigint);
    else hSigint = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
{
    hSigint = NULL;
    signal(SIGINT, on_sigint);
    BuildSomething();
    if (hSigint == NULL)
    {
        hSigint = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        SetSomethingInMotion();
        WaitForSingleObject(hSigint, INFINITE);
    }
    TearSomethingDown();
    return 0;
}
```

Despite a Windows example, Linux answers are welcome too.

Comment: Are you using MSVCRT?

Comment: I think so. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, `SIGINT` is not supported on Windows. See below for more.

Firstly, Windows only supports the minimal signals required by the C specification.

1. SIGABRT Abnormal termination
2. SIGFPE Floating-point error
3. SIGILL Illegal instruction
4. SIGINT CTRL+C signal
5. SIGSEGV Illegal storage access
6. SIGTERM Termination request

Only those signals are supported, and the complex interactions between signals and IO do not occur - e.g. `SIGINT` will not cause in-progress IO to abort, and `SIGALRM` doesn't exist.

- See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12(v=vs.71).aspx

Secondly, all signals except `SIGINT` are called on the same thread which gave rise to the condition. This is because MSVCRT implements those signals as first-chance exceptions using SEH, and SEH exception handlers run on the same thread. This also means that if you handle such an SEH (e.g. Access Violation maps to `SIGSEGV`) with anything other than `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH` then the signal function will NOT get called.

`SIGINT` on the other hand is **not supported on Win32**. The equivalent functionality is `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, which is always calls the handler function on a different thread. If the CRT you are using such as MinGW, Cygwin, or, if it works, MSVCRT, handles SIGINT it will always be on a specially created thread.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx

If it is a windows only application use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` and SEH instead.

If you wish to do the equivalent of sending a signal to another process, you should do this with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`.

Finally, there are generally only two good things to do in signal handlers - either quit (which is the default behaviour anyway), or place a message in some kind of queue for later handling (which is what most high-level languages do, for the simple reason that signals are highly non-portable in behaviour even if not in specification, and it is desirable to get out of the handler as fast as possible.

Comment: Um, but SIGINT *is* supported in Windows. I just wrote an app that successfully employs it. When I set the breakpoint inside the handler, run the app, and press Crtl+C, it breaks in the handler as expected.

Comment: @AnsisMalins, OK, well I have misunderstood the documentation! I can tell you that Ctrl+C is handled by SetConsoleCtrlHandler, so your CRT must be using that. I assume that ***is*** MSVCRT not MinGW or Cygwin?

Comment: @AnsisMalins, Updated answer. Ctr+C will always be called on a separate thread. Ctrl+Break and the window close button, if they are handled as signals, will also be called on a separate thread, as they are implemented in the same way.